# Storing config for test and production

Tags: reactjs

I am searching for a way to store my configs in a file (everything other than .js files for easy changing). Can someone please recommend me a good way.

Thank You JScripter

Comment: Do you want to transfer that config to the frontend? Or use it with SSR?

Comment: I want to use this config at the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .env files to for both development and production configurations.